# How to sum two different sheets of excels in third sheet using phpexcel

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula, phpexcel

Am using PhpExcel Library to export huge details of my database. Anyway i tried to export my details. I just created three different sheets. One sheet name is "Week 1", Another one is "Week 2". Again  the third one name is "Total". I am getting error when add first value of (ie.E5) 'Week 1' and first first value of (ie.E5) 'Week 2'.

If I apply any formula inside the same sheet (Ex: If i add first and second  value of 'Week 1') , it is working fine. But for between the different sheets i am getting Error (Err.No: 509 : "Operator Missing").

Kindly Help Me On This... ! Thankyou in advance. :)

Comment: So show your formula. It should be something like `='Week1'!E5+'Week2'!E5`

Comment: No ... Little change. I used this   `='Week1'.E5+'Week2'.E5`    But not worked.

Comment: @MarkBaker Thankyou. You are right. Now it works after using '!' instead '.'. :)

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry didn't mean to steal your thunder : you did all the hard work! Expect some votes from me in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the difference in the expressions shown in the comments you are missing the exclamation marks "!" (you have "." which is not the same) which tell excel it is not on the current sheet. Mark's version is correct.

Comment: You are right..! Thankyou. I tried now with '!'. It works. You both are awesome.